# Bower define ~/.config location

Tags: npm, bower

I have a user who does not have permissions to create directories in their home directory.

I'm getting some errors when trying to bower install, is it possible for me to define the location of the .config directory from say /.bowerrc or something? As you can with the cache directory and such.

Ideally a solution that will apply to all users on the system.

```
$ bower install

Error: EACCES, permission denied '<snip>/.config'
    at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:647:18)
    at sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:70:13)
    at Function.sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:76:24)
    at Object.create.all.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:41:13)
    at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
    at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:26:34)
    at ensureInsight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/analytics.js:26:19)
    at Object.setup (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/util/analytics.js:43:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/bin/bower:72:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by defining the XDG_CONFIG_HOME environment variable.

See https://superuser.com/questions/365847/where-should-the-xdg-config-home-variable-be-defined